# Where is the Offset Edge feature in Blender 3.2

Tags: edges, 2d, tools

quick question:

Im trying to find the **"Edge > Offset Edges > Offset"** in blender 3.2 while in edit mode having selected a 2d mesh, does anyone know where its gone;

Image below shows where it used to be on Blender 3.0

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean a 2D mesh or a 3D one? - It's still at the top of the Edge menu in Blender 3.2.1 if you mean 3D.

Comment: In my Blender 3.2.0 it's exactly there. I don't know what you mean with a 2D mesh either.

Comment: So its regular mesh, my bad. Say with circle for example:

Image Reference:  https://ibb.co/TtWf55J

Could it be visibility issues; or I have something mixed up here